# move_uploaded_file() function doesn't save uploaded file on server

Tags: php, linux, apache, file-upload

I've been working on a php script which creates a folder and saves posted images in the created folder, the folders get created but the images  I aren't saved.

Below is the script:

```
if (isset($_FILES['images'])) {
    mkdir("files/test/".$new."/", 0755, true);

    foreach ($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'] as $key => $value) {  

        if (!(empty($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key]) || $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key] == 'none')) {

            $i_slika = 1;

            $extenzion = strtolower(end(explode(".", $_FILES['images']['name'][$key])));
            $file = "files/nekretnina/".$new."/".$i_slika.".".$extenzion;

            while (file_exists($file)) {
                $i_slika++;
                $file = "files/nekretnina/".$new."/".$i_slika.".".$extenzion;
            }

            if (!@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key], $file)) {

                $err_text = $err_text. 'Error: '.$_FILES['images']['name'][$key].'<br />';
            } else {
                include_once "thumbz.class.php";

                $pic = new thumbz($file);
                $pic->dimensionImage("resize",640);
                $pic->addParam('l',0);
                $pic->render($file);
            }
        }

    } 
}
```

Comment: So where does `$new` come from

Comment: Try removing the `@` error supressor and maybe you will see a useful error message

Comment: It's a variable that's defined before this script. As I wrote in the post, the creation of folders works (mkdir()) but the images aren't saved in the created folder.

Comment: https://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php when using that, what does it show you? if it shows you that it's unable to move the file, check your path and folder permissions.

Comment: If you do a var_dump() on the $_FILES array after the form is submitted, what do you get?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key]` instead of `$_FILES['slika']['tmp_name'][$key]`.

You have the wrong index name!

Try Using:

```
if (isset($_FILES['images'])) {
    mkdir("files/test/".$new."/", 0755, true);

    foreach ($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'] as $key => $value) {  

        if (!(empty($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key]) || $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key] == 'none')) {

            $i_slika = 1;

            $extenzion = strtolower(end(explode(".", $_FILES['images']['name'][$key])));
            $file = "files/test/".$new."/".$i_slika.".".$extenzion;

            while (file_exists($file)) {
                $i_slika++;
                $file = "files/test/".$new."/".$i_slika.".".$extenzion;
            }

            if (!@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key], $file)) {

                $err_text = $err_text. 'Error: '.$_FILES['images']['name'][$key].'<br />';
            } else {
                include_once "thumbz.class.php";

                $pic = new thumbz($file);
                $pic->dimensionImage("resize",640);
                $pic->addParam('l',0);
                $pic->render($file);
            }
        }

    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I’ve changed that, but I stil have the same issue.